# How does a Java application server decide what charset to send in the HTTP Content-type header?

Tags: java, http

In [my current project](http://mifos.org), I've been forgetting about character encoding and just letting the application server do the right thing. This was working fine for some time. For instance, I was able to switch the locale in my application to Simplified Chinese / China and see the UTF-8 characters just fine in any recent Firefox or Chrome browser. Something changed (I'm still trying to figure out what). Content is still UTF-8 encoded, but sometimes the Content-type header is [setting the charset wrong](http://mifosforge.jira.com/browse/MIFOS-4789):

```
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

...leading to garbage appearing in the browser instead of Chinese characters. If I temporarily force the encoding to UTF-8 in my browser, the characters show up properly.

What would really help nail down the problem is knowing how an application server (or Web dev framework like struts or spring?) decides what to put in this header! Any ideas?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this is because our JSPs are actually in a jar file in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Maybe not. Might be that Struts 1.2.7 can't handle Java properties string bundles with UNICODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What web technology are you using? For instance in servlets you have [ServletResponse#setCharacterEncoding()](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29). In JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Eventually every web framework will end up using one of the two above.

Comment: Our app currently uses both Struts/JSP and SpringMVC/Freemarker. The SpringMVC/Freemarker stuff works, but the Struts/JSP stuff is messing up the charset when the locale is zh_CN. But I tried forcing a different charset in a Struts action class: this doesn't help.

Comment: Do all your JSP pages have UTF-8 charset declaration as above?

Comment: Argh, wait, I'm sorry, the @page JSP directive definitely is doing something, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it was probably something that never should have worked in our app, but just started breaking in Tomcat/Jetty 7.